# How to make Spring Boot track HTTP session without authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-session

I have a simple Spring Boot app. I have created a session-scoped class and want for it to store some session related stuff. I want for the HTTP session to be created and tracked via the JSESSIONID cookie on the first request coming to the server. However, it looks like Spring Boot does not use HTTP session tracking by default (even JSESSIONID cookie is never created). How to enable HTTP session tracking - no user authentication is needed. Just plain JSESSIONID cookie tracking is wanted.

Comment: Just use/access the `HttpSession` in your code (add something to it) and you will get a cookie. The same applies for your session scoped object, it will only be created and placed in the session after you are using it (it will be created lazily), so if you set some values it will be put in there.

Comment: New JSESSIONID get's set on each new request for the same "user". I have tried using `SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED` and `SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER`

Comment: That is for Spring Security and has nothing to do with other session usage on ly the session usage for SPring Security.